# Movie about a prisoner with healing powers

Tags: story-identification

It's an older movie where a prisoner has healing powers and heals a lot of inmates. At the end he's executed but the people he healed brings him back to life. Can't find it anywhere online.

*The Green Mile* reminded me of it but in this one he is brought back to life at the end by all the people he's helped. It might have even been one of those old mini shows like *Tales from the Crypt* or something like that. It's like 15 years ago.

Comment: This is very broad. Can you give us more information such as, how much older, where and when is the movie set, can you remember anything else about it?

Comment: Also, can you remember who starred in it? That would help to narrow it down.

Comment: It might be *Amazing Stories: Life on Death Row*. Similar plot and it includes the details in your comment.

Comment: If so, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167120/tv-show-where-a-condemned-prisoner-can-miraculously-heal-by-touch

Comment: We don't add spoiler tags to ID questions, as the asker knows what they're looking for and the answered is assumed to know the details as they're identifying the story. [Relevant meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10797/im-asking-a-story-id-question-should-i-include-spoilers)

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like an episode of Amazing Stories called [Life on Death Row](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511102/reviews)

> Convicted murderer Eric Peterson, Patrick Swayze,is about to face his maker after holding off his execution with legal maneuvers for some four years.
>
> Recovering from his injury at the prison hospital ward Peterson and the sergeant of the prison guard Meadows, Hector Elizondo, soon realize that he somehow obtain the power to heal.
>
> With the governor not commuting or even granting a stay of execution for Peterson Warden Erhardt, almost in tears, has no choice but to have him juiced with a 2,000 bolt charge of electricity in the prison's execution chamber.

And from [this description](http://www.cracked.com/article_22814_5-huge-movies-that-shamelessly-ripped-off-one-tv-show.html), we have the ending you described

> In Amazing Stories, the inmate is brought back to life thanks to all the people he helped

Interestingly, that last article notes that this episode was from 1986, and King's novel, *The Green Mile*, was published in 1996. The similarities are certainly striking...

Answer (score 4):

It reminds me of [The Green Mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Green_Mile_(film)).  A 1999 film where a prisoner has healing powers.

[image: The Green Mile - movie poster]

Comment: The Green Mile reminded me of it but in this one he brought back to life at the end by all the people he's help. It might have even been one of those old mini shows like tells from the crypt or something like that. It's like 15 years ago