# TV show where a condemned prisoner can miraculously heal by touch

Tags: story-identification

Now to all those who are scrambling to get in first to answer the easiest question ever, I can tell you it's NOT Stephen King's "The Green Mile". I'm absolutely certain I saw it before "The Green Mile" movie and I'm 99% sure I saw it before the book was released.

What I remember:

- I saw it in the late 80s or early 90s.
- It was one of those half hour serial TV shows where a story is built up to a twist, possibly Twilight Zone or Alfred Hitchcock Presents or something similar.
- The condemned man is scheduled to be executed in the coming days/weeks.
- Somehow he is granted the power of healing and heals some of the prisoners and guards.
- The warden hears about it and brings in his young, terminally ill daughter, who the prisoner heals.
- The warden then tries to arrange clemency and/or a pardon. I can't remember if he's successful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movie about a prisoner with healing powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147500/movie-about-a-prisoner-with-healing-powers)

Comment: Sorry, have to leave this open as the other question isn't accepted (even verbally).

Comment: Are you sure it's not "The Green Mile?"

Comment: it's certainly not "The Green Mile" @user973810 :)

Comment: @user973810 This episode aired 10 years before Stephen King wrote the book series *The Green Mile* was based on

Comment: Are you implying Stephen King plagiarized The Green Mile?

Comment: "The warden then tries to arrange clemency and/or a pardon. I can't remember if he's successful." <- he failed. And the prisoner was executed on the electric chair, but was miraculously alive again after that. The story ends with the warden said, "What should we do now?"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The episode is called ***"Life on Death Row"*** and is an episode of the second season of **Amazing Stories** airing in 1986

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511102/

> Life on Death Row follows Eric, a young death row inmate (Patrick
>   Swayze) whose final appeal on his verdict was rejected, and he’s
>   slated for execution in 24 hours. After an accident in a desperate and
>   failed escape attempt, Eric develops the amazing ability to heal
>   people by touch – and his life take a whole new direction, just when
>   there’s so little time before they are claimed by the hangman.

[image]

Additional notes from the SFF Planet site re: this episode relevant to the question:

> The story bears many similarities to Stephen King’s acclaimed novel
>   The Green Mile (and its 1999 big-screen adaptation directed by Frank
>   Darabont), but the episode was broadcasted many years before King
>   wrote his book – and perhaps it’s not a coincidence that in his post
>   Amazing Stories career, Garris became a prolific writer and director
>   of Stephen King adaptations in both cinema and television some (The
>   Stand) successful, others less so.

http://www.sffplanet.com/space-oddities-amazing-stories-life-on-death-row-mick-garris-1986/

Comment: That looks like it, thank you.

Comment: I was 100% sure that OP was talking about The Green Mile. Those stories indeed sound curiously similar.